# error: expected expression before struct

Tags: c, array, struct, lista-encadeada

Por que ta dando erro? Why?

Error = |21|error: expected expression before 'ListaSimples'|

```
#define MAX 25

typedef struct Rota Rota;
typedef struct ListaRota ListaRota;
typedef struct ListaSimples ListaSimples;
typedef struct ListaDupla ListaDupla;

struct ListaSimples{
    ListaRota *rotas;
    ListaDupla *dados;
    int tamanho;
};

struct ListaRota{
    ListaRota *proximo;
    char *dado[MAX];
};

struct ListaDupla{
    Rota *info;
    int tam[ListaSimples->tamanho];
};

struct Rota{
    Rota *anterior;
    Rota *sucessor;
    char *nomecidade[MAX];
    char *descricao[MAX*2];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### **O Erro**

Repare nessa parte:

```
int tam[ListaSimples->tamanho];
```

Qual é o valor de `ListaSimples->tamanho`? Aparentemente esse é seu erro.
`ListaSimples->tamanho` não é um valor, pois `ListaSimples`, no seu código, é um tipo de dado que você criou e por isso essa expressão é inválida.

### **Solução**

Não sei exatamente qual é o seu objetivo, mas aparentemente o tamanho de `int tam[ListaSimples->tamanho];` é indefinido, ou seja, pode variar para cada execução. Se não sabe o tamanho então deve usar-se [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). Exemplo:

```
/* Declare como um ponteiro */
int *tam;

/* Faça a alocação quando de fato for criar o objeto */
int *tam = malloc(/* Aqui vai o tamanho */);
```

**OBS:** Não esqueça de dar [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) para cada ponteiro que você utilizou o `malloc`.

Comment: entendi, esqueci que o tamanho do vetor tem q ser inicializado

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ListaDupla{
    Rota *info;
    int tam[ListaSimples->tamanho];
};
```

O erro esta em int tam[**ListaSimples->tamanho**]; nas structs ou metes um valor certo ou usas um ponteiro a nao ser que uses algo mais complexo, em certas revisões de C
da para fazeres int tam[] e depois definir mais tarde eis um exemplo

```
extern const int n;
typedef struct
{
    int len;
    char p[];
} str;
void foo(void)
{
    size_t str_size = sizeof(str);  // equivalent to offsetoff(str, p)
    str *s = malloc(str_size + (sizeof(char) * n));
}
```